# Is my proof right and enough?: A non-convergent series of non-negative terms diverges to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

"Proof that a non-convergent series of non-negative terms diverges to infinity"

I just want to be sure that my proof is right and complete. Could someone help me to check it?

**My attempt:**

Let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ be a non-convergent series of non-negative terms and let $M>0$, since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ is non convergent, it does not converges to zero, then there exists $N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that:

$$\left| \sum_{m=1}^{N_1} x_n \right| = \sum_{m=1}^{N_1} x_n \geq M$$

Since $x_n \geq 0$ for all $n$ and since the series is non convergent, there must be an infinite amount of terms that are strictly greater than zero (otherwise the series would converge to the finite sum of positive terms). Hence, there exists $N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that:

$$ \sum_{m=1}^n x_n > \sum_{m=1}^{N_1} x_n \geq M$$ for all $n \geq N_2$

Which completes the proof.

Comment: It seems to me that your first inequality essentially assumes the statement to be true.

Comment: @RishiSonthalia: That is sufficient, but it isn't necessarily the case, for instance $x_n = 1/n$ does not satisfy that property.

Comment: Sorry, I read it as the sequence is not convergent

Comment: I think you are trying to prove that if the individual terms are non-negative and do not converge to $0$ as a sequence then the series sum is infinite.  In a handwaving sense, if at least $n$ of them exceed $\epsilon>0$ and all the others are non-negative then the sum is at least $n\epsilon$, and the sequence not converging says that for any $\epsilon>0$ you have an unbounded $n$ such cases, so the sum is indeed infinite.

Comment: To me, the following sentence has not been justified:
$$$$
Let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ be a non-convergent series of non-negative terms and let $M>0.$ Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ is non convergent, it does not converges to zero, so there exists $N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that:

$$\left| \sum_{m=1}^{N_1} x_n \right| = \sum_{m=1}^{N_1} x_n \geq M$$

Comment: If the terms are non-negative then the series is increasing.  Haven't you had a theorem that any increasing sequence that is bounded above is convergent?  Then this is just the contrapositive.  As this incresing series is *not* convergent then it can't be bounded above.

Comment: " since ∑∞n=1xn is non convergent, it does not converges to zero, then there exists N1∈N

such that:

∣∣∣∣∑m=1N1xn∣∣∣∣=∑m=1N1xn≥M"  Why on earth would *that* follow?  (And that is what you are trying to prove).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way of thinking :

A series of non negative reals either convergent or diverges to $+ \infty$.

Let us consider the series of non negative reals $\sum_{n} x_n$ , then the sequence of partial sum $S_n =\sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k$ is an increasing sequence.

If it is bounded  then converges to $\sup\{S_n : n\in \Bbb{N}\}$ otherwise diverges to $+\infty$.

---

---

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ not convergent implies the sequence $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k$ is not convergent.

Since $(S_n) $ is an increasing sequence (!) and $(S_n) $ doesn't converge implies $(S_n) $ is unbounded above and $(S_n) \to +\infty$ .
Hence  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n $ diverges to $+\infty$

---

Everything about a series of non negative terms reduced to a increasing sequence whose behavior is very much known.

Answer (score 2):

"Not convergent to zero" only implies there exists **some** $M>0$ so that for infinitely many $N$, $$|\sum_{n=1}^Na_n|>M.$$ It isn't necessarily the case that you can choose $M$ arbitrarily large here. What this means is that "not converging to zero" isn't using the full strength of the assumption that the series does not converge.

As a suggestion, try using the Cauchy criterion for convergence to prove the claim instead.